# Reading json file in pyspark with out changing old schema

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I received the json every day with 10 attributes but some days if any attribute has no value they will send the 9 attributes and 10th attribute has not there in json. How can I read the json file in pyspark without changing old table schema

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should enforce a [`schema`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L92) when reading the files.
I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
df = spark.read.json(path_to_json_files)
```

In order to preserve all the attributes/fields, use the schema like so:

```
df = spark.read.schema(file_schema).json(path_to_json_files)
```

To get the `file_schema` you can use an old file(s) that you know every attribute is available:

```
file_schema = spark.read.json(full_json_file).schema
```